# After inputting number in EditText, next button keyboard takes user to a different EditText automatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, genymotion

Making a simple calorie converter.

Here's the problem in pictures.

I'm on a Genymotion emulator.

Here is the part of the screen I'm having issues with:
[image]

When I click on an EditText number field, the numberpad comes up
[image]

But there's a next arrow I must click which takes me to the next input field
[image]

Before I can finally just get out of the numberpad.

What's going on? After I type in a number into one edit text I want it to end right there, not jump to the next Edit Text. Also, it's weird because if I enter a number in the two bottom EditTexts they end right away whereas if I enter a number in the top EditTexts they take me to one of the bottom EditTexts.

Here's the XML file.

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView4" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView5" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText2" />
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: This happens because of the `android:inputType="number" its the default response for the key being pressed with that input type. You can handle what happens when the enter key is pressed, there are multiple answers already on stackoverflow

Comment: @NicolasTyler I purposefully did want a number input type. My problem is that I can't get to the enter key before it jumps to some other number input. I've already looked through StackOverflow, I'm super new to this Android development as in I started learning today, and the things that might help me are in Java which I would prefer not to deal with right now and some other thing that doesn't exist any more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to jump next field you mentioned the id in editText itself using nextFocusDown attribute.

try this....

```
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView2" 
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText3"/>
```

when you want to show done on SoftKeyboard at particular view use  android:imeOptions="actionDone" attribute.

Comment: Thanks, android:imeOptions="actionDone" was what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Set ime options to your EditText:

```
 <EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    ... />
```

You can choose from various options. See the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions

Answer (score 0):

The only way to truly handle what happens when the next (enter) key is pressed is to make a listener for it at tell it what to do according to the current state of the application.

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Perform action on key press
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

To select a edittext you need to focus it like this:

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Simple solution would be to add:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/..." <!--Obviously with the next edittext ID--
```